# Модели в asp.net mvc и Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, entity-framework

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть пара вопросов вопрос связанных с моделями в asp.net mvc.

Вопрос первый. Допустим у меня есть некая БД. Доступ к ней я осуществляю через Entity Framework. Эта библиотека генерирует для моих таблиц классы которые я потом могу использовать. Но тут возникает вопрос: а как быть с моделью? Если использовать эти сгенерированные сущности в качестве моделей то я не смогу как либо их изменять (например добавлять атрибуты для валидации) ведь эти сущности автоматически сгенерированы и редактировать их в общем нельзя. А если создавать свои модели то в 90% случаев получится что эти модели будут обертками над  вышеупомянутыми сущностями из Entity ведь в БД в основном хранятся данные отражающие модели.

И теперь второй вопрос. По сути эти модели - это DTO то есть просто объекты содержащие только данные. А как быть с логикой обработки этих данных? Она должна быть в контроллерах что ли? Но насколько я знаю контроллеры в Asp.net mvc должны быть "тонкими", то есть не содержать особой логики. Или надо писать еще и дополнительные контроллеры в которых будет сосредоточена логика работы с моделями? Как тут быть подскажите знающие люди!

Answer (score 5):

Стандартная трехуровневая архитектура подразумевает разделение приложения на три слоя:

- Presentation - UI
- Logic - Service Level
- Data - Database, или еще какой-то метод хранения данных

MVC - это паттерн для организации UI.

Роль контроллеров в этом паттерне - обработка действий пользователя. В них могут быть:

- вызовы бизнес логики - методов классов сервисного уровня (сервисов не в смысле WCF, а в смысле каких-то классов из Service Level)
- конвертация данных в/из DTO сервисного уровня в модели для Presentation (возможно вы ищете [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)?)
- еще какая-то UI-логика, не подразумевающая работу с объектами домена - редиректы, сессии, кэширование и прочее.

Т.е. например создание заказа (классический пример) выглядит так:

- Пользователь заполняет форму жмет на кнопку "создать заказ"
- Вызывается OrdersController.Create
  Controller собирает данные для вызова сервиса - лежащие в корзине товары (из сессии), id пользователя, адрес (пришедший с клиента по нажатию кнопки).
- Контроллер дергает сервисный уровень - OrderService.CreateOrder(...), отдавая ему все собранное
- OrderService создает контекст, создает новый Order,... вобщем занимается бизнес логикой в чистом виде.
- OrderService выдает наверх Order или OrderDTO
- Контроллер выбирает из этого Order поля, необходимые для отображения вида - номер заказа, например. И собирает из них модель.
- Контроллер возвращает вид "OrderConfirmed" с моделью.

Просто в стандартных примерах по MVC обычно делают то, что ни в коем случае не стоит делать в живом приложении - например, вообще упоминать DataContext в коде контроллера. Или дергать методы репозитория.

Это делается только ради упрощения - примеры должны показать разницу между M V и C.

При этом считается, что разделение между Presentation-Logic-Data - это нечто само собой разумеющееся.

Answer (score 4):

1. да можешь использовать мета данные, создаешь partial class в той же пространстве имен где у сгенерировал тебе модели Entity Framework.

Например для AspNetUser.cs:

```
namespace Project.Data
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(AspNetUserMetaData))]
    public partial class AspNetUser
    {

    }

    public class AspNetUserMetaData
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Почта")]
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Телефон")]
        [Required]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
        public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Логин")]
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2. Советую использовать паттерн "Репозиторий", подробный описание [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/11.php) и [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/52173/). Но лучше использовать паттерн "[generic repository](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/838097/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Pat)".

Answer (score 2):

Модели для asp.net mvc нужно создавать свои потому что это модель представления которая не часто совпадает с моделью в базе данных 1 к 1. Логика по хорошему должна быть вообще отдельно от сайта, например в WCF Services, контроллеры asp.net делают только вызовы в нужном порядке этих WCF сервисов обьединяя их в одну транзакцию.

Comment: насчет моделей понял, спасибо. Но вот с логикой и вынесением ее в WCF по моему несколько перебор. Во-первых это лишние расходы времени на общение с wcf а во-вторых почему бы не написать какие-то классы репозитории, провайдеры, контроллеры  или что-то в этом роде чтобы они выполняли нужную логику?

Comment: Ну тогда заведите себе namespace BusinessLogic { и создавайте классы для работы с логикой } и вызывайте в asp.net контроллерах.

Comment: WCF это для больших распределенных веб приложений нужно.